# Prevent CMake from looking into PATH for libraries and includes

Tags: cmake

Consider the simple CMake script below trying to find a fictional `theheader.h` C header file. As far as I know, this is the typical way to locate the include directory of a library in the `FindXXX.cmake` modules.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(test)

find_path(
    TEST_INCLUDES
    NAMES "theheader.h"
)

message(STATUS "TEST_INCLUDES: ${TEST_INCLUDES}")
```

Now assume that, in a way unrelated to this CMake script, I have edited my `PATH` environment variable (I'm running Linux) to contain a custom `bin` directory:

```
PATH="/home/cschreib/someapp/bin:$PATH"
```

Turns out, the directory `/home/cschreib/someapp/include` exists, and contains a file named `theheader.h`. This header was only used locally to build `someapp`, it was never meant to be used by other programs*.

Before CMake 3.3, this custom location was never found by CMake. However, starting with version 3.3, CMake tries to be smart and substitutes `bin` for `include` for all directories in `$PATH`. Therefore, CMake 3.3 (and above) does find `theheader.h` in this custom directory. Because this was never intended, this is causing all sorts of trouble, including a mismatch between headers and shared objects versions.

I know I can tell CMake not to look in `$PATH` by using the `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` option in `find_path`, but I am looking for a more generic solution to this issue. Indeed, this problem can happen for any library. I could make a copy of all the FindXXX.cmake modules I need and systematically add the `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` option, but I would rather avoid this.

Is there a global switch I could use to turn off this unwanted feature? Or some other way out?

*: Before someone comments on this. I am aware this is not good practice. I am also aware that, in my community, people tend not to care much about good and bad practices, and this situation is very common. Since I am not going to change the community, I want my CMake scripts to be robust against bad practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior was removed again for non-Windows platform with CMake version 3.6.

If you run into this problem just update the the latest CMake version. See version 3.6 release notes [Deprecated and Removed Features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/release/3.6.html#deprecated-and-removed-features):

> The `find_library()`, `find_path()`, and `find_file()` commands no longer search in installation prefixes derived from the `PATH` environment variable on non-Windows platforms. This behavior was added in CMake 3.3 to support Windows hosts but has proven problematic on UNIX hosts. Users that keep some `<prefix>/bin` directories in the PATH just for their tools do not necessarily want any supporting `<prefix>/lib` directories searched. One may set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable with a ;-list of prefixes that are to be searched.

Comment: Good they changed it back! I'll go for the upgrade then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, such a switch does not exist in CMake 3.5. I would not try working around this, because even if you hack it with regard to CMake, this might still confuse compilers or users.

Where are the headers from? Can you ask one of the projects to change the header? Usually projects don't want to clash with other libraries and try to address such issues.

Comment: The issue happened with FFTW, which is installed globally through my distribution's repository, but was also shipped with a program I had to compile myself. I can, of course, remove these headers manually since they are not needed any more. But I guess the point of my question was to avoid such manual intervention, which is sometimes undesirable and always confusing for the user. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: You could just leave it. CMake will find one version and just use this. But Florian answers your question the right way.