# If statement in Cmake does not work

Tags: cmake

Hello I have the following code, and I expect that if the library doesn't exist cmake throw an error

```
find_library( lx
          NAMES libx.a
          HINTS "/home/username/HDF_SOURCES/lib")
if(NOT lx)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "libx.a not found")
endif()
```

I have also tried if(lx-NOTFOUND) but cmake runs successfully even though library doesn't exist. !! ?

The confusing part is if I change the loop with if(lx) and the library path is wrong than it throws an error. How is this possible ? did I understand something wrongly ?

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657195/how-to-test-if-cmake-found-a-library-with-find-library) answer

Comment: Are you sure `lx` is not cached?

Comment: `find_library()` does store its results in a cached variable. So if it did only once find the library, it won't run the search again. Try an `unset(lx CACHE`) before the `find_library()` call to verify this.

Comment: no it wasnt cached, I kept deleting the files.

Comment: I added NO_DEFAULT_PATH and it works now ? do you know why this could be ?

Answer (score 0):

adding NOT_DEFAULT_PATH solved the issue, now it behaves exactly how it is supposed to

```
find_library( lx
          NAMES lib.a
          HINTS "/home/username/lib"
          NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

if (NOT lx)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "lib.a not found")
endif()
```

Comment: Does anyone know why this happened ?

Comment: Your library was found in one of the default paths?

Comment: What is the definition of a DEFAULT_PATH ? I searched but I couldn't find one. Unless it tried to search my home folder, it is unlikely.

Comment: If a library was found the result in in `lx`. So just do `message("lx = ${lx}")`. Regarding your question maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668024/prevent-cmake-from-looking-into-path-for-libraries-and-includes) helps.

Comment: ***What is the definition of a DEFAULT_PATH ?*** The help has some info: `cmake --help-command find_package`

Comment: Your question is poor and not helpful for others. Your answer contains a severe typo.

Comment: I got to see after many days that there was another(totally unrelated) library with the same in /usr/local I deleted the library and the original cmake code worked fine. Nevertheless I find that during development since I keep using my own libraries NOT_DEFAULT_PATH has been useful to me. @usr1234567 I am sure it is not helpful for a pro like you ;)